How do I use a property for the value of an <input>?
I'd like a reactive property to be "bound" to the value of an <input> element. I can achieve this using various approaches, such as using @change(...), but I wonder if there is a more canonical way of doing it?
import {html, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  @property()
  name: string = 'Somebody';

  render() {
    return html`
        <input .value=${this.name}>
        <p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>
        `;
  }
}

Try it out here

Use input Event Listener as follows:
import { html, css, LitElement } from 'lit';
import { customElement, property } from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`p { color: blue }`;
  
  @property()
  name = 'Somebody';

  render() {
    return html`
      <input .value=${this.name} @input=${this._onInput}>
      <p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>
    `;
  }

  private _onInput(event: Event) {
    this.name = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  }
}

Demo Code

Thanks! I was hoping there was a way to avoid that boilerplatey event handler, along with that ugly as HTMLInputElement, but I guess it's the best one can do.
